# How to root Bluetimes 3584F Android TV box?

Tags: rooting

I need to move the apps to SD card because the internal memory is almost full, but I can do that only if it is rooted. So, I need to root my Android TV Box, *Bluetimes 3584F*.

This is the firmware link to download and the guide as install it on Android TV Box: [firmware_Bluetimes_3584F.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8HeDtooMzilRDlvNld1RHI2eEE)

Upgrading guide:

> 1. Unzip the downloaded firmware file, you will get 4 files named "g18ref-ota-XXXX.zip", "factory_update_param.aml", "u-boot.bin" and
>      "recovery.img".
> 2. Copy the 4 files to the root directory of your SD card.
> 3. Take off the power adapter from your media player and insert SD card to the card reader slot.
> 4. Press and hold the reset hole on the back of the media player(beside the power socket), then connect power adapter to this
>      item, still holding the reset hole
> 5. When you see the upgrading process bar showed on your TV screen, you can release the reset hole.
>
> After firmware updating finished, TV box will reboot automatically.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the `utoo-root-signed.zip` file from [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=38374383) and move it to SD card.
2. Download the `firmware_Bluetimes_3584F.zip` file in question, unzip it and move the files quoted below to SD card:

   - `factory_update_param.aml`
   - `u-boot.bin`
   - `recovery.img`
3. Rename the `utoo-root-signed.zip` inside of SD card to `g18ref-ota-20131220.zip`.
4. Do the steps **3**, **4** and **5** of the "Upgrading guide" in question.

P.S.: Even with the phone rooted I needed to create a 2nd partition EXT4 on SD card to move the apps to it by Link2SD app.

Thank you very much to **stane1983**.